# (Android) How do I set the voice recognition language to something that I choose?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

How do I set the voice recognition language to something that I choose?

For example, is there something that I can set to change the voice recognition language?

I am using the following code, but I do not know how to specify the language.

What can I do?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
 RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, prompt);
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the RecognizerIntent before. But it seems like there is an extra that you can put for selecting a different language

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE

I would think that if you make another putExtra() call and pass it that constant and a string in the proper form ("en-US") it would set the language.

However I don't know and don't see anywhere on there exactly how many / which languages are supported. So you may have limited success trying to have it use different languages.

I would think something like this would do the trick:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```

you just need to find the bcp47 compliant language tag for the language you are interested in.

Comment: can you write simple example . one line?

Comment: that is the only one that I know yes. I beleive es, and fr are spanish and french respectively. But don't know if they would need a country specification like the US one has.